# VBScript/ creación de carpeta/recorrer rutas

Tags: asp, vb6, vbscript

Soy nueva en VBscript y ustedes ya me ayudaron anteriormente así que confío que lo harán nuevamente(son muy amables).

Lo que necesito hacer es lo siguiente:

- Proceso que lea rutas de carpetas, verifique si esa ruta de carpeta contiene un archivo de extensión(ej. PDF y HTML) y si tiene,  los copie y los pegue en otra carpeta final, que se debe crear con la fecha del día.
  Si no encuentra ningún archivo con la extensión especificada en alguna ruta de carpeta, que salte a la siguiente ruta y así sucesivamente.

Por ahora tengo listo el proceso de lectura de solo UNA ruta, donde copia los archivos y los lleva a una carpeta final

Me falta:
- Creación de la carpeta con la fecha del día.
- Realización del proceso con mas de una ruta
- Verificación de existencia del algún archivo con esa o esas extensiones
- Si no encuentra que salte a la próxima ruta
- Si encuentra que ejecute el proceso

Código 1:
Proceso de lectura de una ruta y copia-pega en otra carpeta ya creada

```
Dim ruta1, ruta_final
ruta1 = "C:\rutaA\*.html"  
ruta_final = "C:\ruta_final"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

fso.CopyFile (ruta1, ) , (ruta_final)
```

-----ERROR: El subíndice está fuera del intervalo (Línea 26-última línea)----
[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

En este caso lo mejor sería crear una función a la que le pasas los parámetros:

**Función:**

```
Function copiarPorExtension(sFolderOrigen, sFolderDestino, sExtension)
   For Each sFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFolderOrigen).Files
      If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(sFile)) = sExtension Then
         If Not oFSO.FileExists(sFolderDestino & "\" &  oFSO.GetFileName(sFile)) Then
           oFSO.GetFile(sFile).Copy sFolderDestino & "\" & oFSO.GetFileName(sFile),True
         End If  
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

**Preparar los parámetros y llamar la función desde cualquier parte**

```
Dim sOrigen, sDestino, sExtension, dtmValue, sFecha, sHora
sOrigen = "C:\rutaA\"  

'Para obtener la fecha
'Almacenaré la fecha en la variable sFecha y la hora en la variable sHora
'En el ejemplo se crea el nombre de carpeta con la fecha, si quieres que tenga la hora le agregas la variable sHora 

dtmValue = Now()

sFecha = Year(dtmValue)"_" & Month(dtmValue) & "_" & Day(dtmValue) 
sHora = strDate & "\" & Hour(dtmValue) & "-" & Minute(dtmValue) & "-" & Second(dtmValue)
sDestino = "C:\ruta_final" & sFecha
sExtension = "html"

'Llamamos la función pasándole los parámetros

Call copiarPorExtension(sOrigen, sDestino, sExtension)
```

La ventaja de la función es que, en el caso de querer pasar otros parámetros, como trabajar con archivos de extensión txt, doc u otros o con directorios distintos, no necesitas cambiar todo el código, sino solamente los parámetros que pasas a la función.

**Si son varios directorios de origen**
Se crea un array con los nombres de los directorios y se pasa como parámetro.
Nótese que la función `copiarPorExtension ()` quedaría modificada, ya que recibirá como primer parámetro un array, en lugar de una cadena, por eso el primer parámetro se llama ahora `arrOrigenes()` donde las () indican que se trata de un array.

Luego, tendrá otro bucle for donde irá leyendo las diferentes carpetas de origen que recibió en parámetro, donde `arrOrigenes(i)`irá tomando la ruta de los folders existentes en el array (LaRutadelFolder1, LaRutadelFolder2, etc).

Nota: Aquí solo modifico el valor de `arrFoldersOrigen`, los demás valores se declararían tal y como aparece más arriba.

```
Dim arrFoldersOrigen
arrFoldersOrigen = Array ("LaRutadelFolder1","LaRutadelFolder2","LaRutadelFolder3")
i=0
```

Para llamar la función:

`Call copiarPorExtension`**`(arrFoldersOrigen,`**`sDestino, sExtension)`

---

```
Function copiarPorExtension(arrOrigenes(), sFolderDestino, sExtension)
   For i=0 to ubound(arrOrigenes)
      For Each sFile In oFSO.GetFolder(arrOrigenes(i)).Files
         If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(sFile)) = sExtension Then
            If Not oFSO.FileExists(sFolderDestino & "\" &  oFSO.GetFileName(sFile)) Then
               oFSO.GetFile(sFile).Copy sFolderDestino & "\" & oFSO.GetFileName(sFile),True
            End If  
         End If
       Next
   Next
End Function
```

*Como detalle y aclaración:*
Lo mismo se podría hacer si se desea pasar varias extensiones, se crea un array de extensiones y se le pasa a la función. Entonces habría que crear otro bucle for dentro de cada folder para que busque las extensiones pasadas en el array.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu rápida respuesta, pero cómo lo hago si son varias rutas de origen?

Comment: Si son varias rutas de origen se puede modificar la función y en vez de ponerle el parámetro sFoldersOrigen se le pone un array en el que estén todas las rutas que quieras evaluar. Ahora modifico la respuesta añadiendo esa parte.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Hola, sabes que me tira un error, no sé si mi código quedó bien estructurado, comentaré una imagen en el post inicial,

Comment: En la llamada tienes que pasar el `arrOrigenes` sin los paréntesis, es decir: `Call copiarPorExtension(arrOrigenes,sDestino, sExtension)`. Para próximas preguntas, se recomienda colocar el texto directamente en vez de imágenes, ya que, ocupan más espacio y si los usuarios están conectados desde el teléfono móvil se dificulta bastante la visualización de imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer un tipo de substring para detectar los últimos dígitos del nombre del archivo y así saber que tipo de extensión tiene.

Ejemplo:

```
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set directory = fso.GetFolder(".").Files

for each file in directory
if Mid(file.NAME,len(file.NAME)-4,4) = ".html" AND Mid(file.NAME,len(file.NAME)-3,4) = ".pdf" then
   'Aqui pones tu codigo
end if
next
```